# nginx - direct multiple subdomain to directory of subdomain name

Tags: nginx

I would like to direct multiple (but specific) subdomains in a single server block to a path of the same name, using proxy_pass:

api.example.com to [www.example.com/api](http://www.example.com/api)
webhook.example.com to [www.example.com/webhook](http://www.example.com/webhook)
iframe.example.com to [www.example.com.webook](http://www.example.com.webook)

This directs all requests from `api`, `webhook`, and `iframe` to `/api`, but I would like to direct `api` to `/api`, `webhook` to `/webhook` etc.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    #tls/ssl certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.key;

    #specify subdomains
    server_name api.example.com webhook.example.com iframe.example.com;

    #reverse proxy to localhost
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/api$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host "www.example.com";
    }
}
```

Is it possible to specify the primary directory as a function of the subdomain, or does this need to be three separate server blocks?

Comment: Use a [regular expression `server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) to capture the subdomain.

Comment: @RichardSmith so in that case I would assume that it is likely that 3 separate blocks is more efficient

Comment: If you only have three specific subdomains, then three `server` blocks would be the most efficient solution. If all of your `server` blocks use the same certificate, those statements could be moved outside and inherited.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, they use a wildcard, so moving the certs out of the block and into the http block would allow Nginx to cache those certificates between all the blocks, while if I had them separately listed in each block, it would lose this benefit, correct?

Comment: Not sure if there is any performance benefit, but it simplifies the server block and removes redundancy.